# not able to npm install optipng in widnows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

When i try to `npm install optipng-bin` getting error as

```
(node:18016) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.

optipng-bin@7.0.0 postinstall D:\node_modules\optipng-bin

node lib/install.js

(node:9868) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.

  ‼ self signed certificate in certificate chain

  ‼ optipng pre-build test failed

  i compiling from source

  × Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "./configure --with-system-zlib --prefix="D:\node_modules\optipng-bin\vendor" --bindir="D:\node_modules\optipng-bin\vendor""
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1):

After going through [this issue on GH](https://github.com/imagemin/optipng-bin/issues/84), I tried these commands:

```
npm rebuild
npm i
```

and it solved my problem.